# Using auto and decltype for making a function return the type of its class. How can I make it return a value, instead of a reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, auto, decltype

I am trying to make a generic, purely virtual Matrix class that supports methods that return a mew Matrix. Of course, if one of those methods is used on a subclass of Matrix it should return something of the subclass type, instead of a Matrix.

Currently my code is something like this:

```
class Matrix
{
    virtual auto transposed() const -> decltype (*this) = 0 ;
} ;

class DenseMatrix : Matrix
{
    auto transposed() const -> decltype (*this)
    {
        DenseMatrix res ;
        // Do some magic

        return res ;
    }
} ;
```

However, since decltype(*this) is of type DenseMatrix& instead of DenseMatrix, the code fails because it ends up returning a reference to a local variable.

How can I tell C++ that I want to return a value instead of a reference? Alternatively, is there any cleaner way of achieving virtual functions returning the type of the class they are being called from?

Comment: You can't have a value of an abstract type, so you can't have a `Matrix` return value in your abstract base class, it has to be a reference or a (smart) pointer.

Comment: Also you can't override a base class's function with a function that returns a different type unless that type is a pointer or reference and the overridden return type a derived class of the original return type.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove the reference from a type, you could simply use `std::remove_reference`.

Yet, another general solution to this kind of problem is to use static polymorphism aka CRTP:

```
struct MatrixBase
{
     // here goes all stuff which is independent of the actual matrix,
     // like number of rows, columns, etc.
};

template<typename Derived>
struct Matrix : public MatrixBase
{
     virtual auto transposed() const -> Derived
     {
           return static_cast<Derived const&>(*this).transposed();
     }
     // ...
};

struct DenseMatrix : public Matrix<DenseMatrix>
{
     virtual auto transposed() const override -> DenseMatrix
     { /* implementation */ }
     // ...
};
```

Such a strategy is usually a bit faster than using dynamic polymorphism vis base class pointers. CRTP is used, for instance, also by the library Eigen.

Answer (score 3):

The following is off the cuff, and not fully tested. However I find myself wondering if the well known handle/body idiom might be a good match for your requirements here.  It works by making `Matrix` nothing but a pointer to an implementation (what you currently call `Matrix`).  And then derived clients derive from the implementation, not from `Matrix` itself.

Here's a small sketch:

```
#include <memory>

class Matrix
{
public:
    class Imp
    {
    public:
        virtual ~Imp() = default;
        virtual auto transposed() const -> std::unique_ptr<Imp> = 0;
    };

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Imp> data_;
public:
    Matrix() = default;

    explicit Matrix(std::unique_ptr<Imp> data)
        : data_(std::move(data)) {}

    auto transposed() const -> Matrix
    {
        return Matrix(data_ ? data_->transposed() : nullptr);
    }
};

class DenseMatrix
    : public Matrix::Imp
{
public:
    virtual auto transposed() const -> std::unique_ptr<Imp>
    {
        std::unique_ptr<DenseMatrix> res(new DenseMatrix);
        // Do some magic
        return std::move(res);
    }
};
```

It means all of your data must be on the heap.  But that is probably going to happen anyway in a situation like this.

External clients just deal with `Matrix`, which is not a base class, but a "handle" to a pointer to the base class.  New implementations derive from the internal base class instead of from the `Matrix` class itself.

It doesn't work all of the time.  And I've glossed over details like how the client is going to specify he wants (e.g.) `DenseMatrix` as opposed to some other type of `Matrix`.  But this general data structure can sometimes be quite useful.

Comment: Wow, this is an extremely complicated solution to an apparently simple problem. I guess it's a symptom that my approach to it is wrong.
I could also make Matrix a nonpure virtual function, and make transposed() return a decltype(remove_reference<*this>), but it's just a different ugly solution.